# Rails attribute on manual array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller I have:

```
@payment_types = [['Cash' ,'1'], ['Card', '2']]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to show in view Cash and Card while writing on database 1 and 2.

In my view I tried:

```
<% payment_types.each do |payment_type| %>
  <%= payment_type %>
<% end %>
```

which shows `['Cash' ,'1'] ['Card', '2']]`

How can I show instead in my view Cash or Card?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you want to show only `'Cash'`, and `'Card'`, you can do it by passing another argument (responsible for hash value, I called it `_` because it's a convention for unused arguments) to your block, like this:

```
<% payment_types.each do |payment_type, _| %>
  <%= payment_type %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it like this

```
<% payment_types.each do |payment_type| %>
  <%= payment_type.first %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes this works too, and I can access also to payment_type.second etc.. Good to know.. Thanks!

Comment: This way you can add extra content to youre arrays and still can acces this from payment_type